# How to fix an x and y scrolling conflict in a slider on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hammer.js

I have a slider that is using the Hammer.js library to detect the touch evens done by the user. thats the code:

```
//init hammer function
var element = document.getElementById('pinwall-grid');
var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("drag", function (event) {
    direction = event.gesture.direction;
    if (direction == 'left') {
        var $meN = $('.pinwall-grid .ctrl a.next');
        if (!$meN.hasClass("nextD")) {
            $meN.trigger('click');
        }
        console.log('left');
    } else if (direction == 'right') {
        var $meP = $('.pinwall-grid .ctrl a.prev');
        if (!$meP.hasClass("prevD")) {
            $meP.trigger('click');
        }
        console.log('right');
    }

    event.gesture.stopDetect();
});
```

The problem is that when you try to scroll on mobile to view the elements that come after the slider (Normal y scrolling). Nothing happens if your finger is on the slider.
How can I make it so that when you swipe up and down, it scrolls normally event if your finger is on the slider, while keeping the left and right swiping options.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: html css code ?

Comment: its a post Feed Slider. The Css and HTML are basic so i didn't see the need to add them.